# Kmeans clustering in QGIS not displaying results in attribute table

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, clustering

I'm new to QGIS and trying to cluster my points using the kmeans method from the attribute based clustering package. I am using latitude and longitude fields each with equal weights. I run the algorithm and it says "Done!" but when I go to my attribute table there the column that tells me the clusters isn't there. Am I missing something?